# Pass XML file as input parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, xml

Is it possible to pass an XML file as a parameter in a stored procedure in SQL Server?
I have tried this but it doesn't do what its supposed to:

```
DECLARE @XmlString2 as XML <--I have a feeling this is the problem
SET @XmlString2 = 'cast(x as XML)
from openrowset (bulk '''+@FileName+''', single_blob) as T(x)'

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL for
SELECT 
    PA_ID = XTbl.value('(Answer_ID)[1]', 'varchar(400)'),
    Question_ID = XTbl.value('(../../ID)[1]', 'bigint'),
    QuestionText = XTbl.value('(../../QuestionText)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),
    QuestionType = XTbl.value('(../../QuestionType)[1]','bigint'),
    Questionaire_ID = XTbl.value('(../../QuestionaireID)[1]','bigint'),
    Filter = XTbl.value('(../../Filter)[1]', 'bigint'),
    Value = XTbl.value('(Value)[1]','varchar(400)'),
    RequiresExplanation = XTbl.value('(RequiresExplanation)[1]','int'),
    ReviewRequired = XTbl.value('(ReviewRequire)[1]','char(1)')

    from @XmlString2.nodes('/Questions/Question/PossibleAnswers/PossibleAnswer') as XD(XTbl)
```

I have the same thing with a hardcoded address of the file and it works, so I was wondering if this is possible so as I can execute the stored procedure with a different file if I need to

Comment: so where's the part where you try to pass the xml to the stored procedure?  What error are you getting?

Comment: @TabAlleman I try: EXEC myProcedure '@'FileName = 'C:\myXML.xml' I don't get an error, it says it was successfull but nothing inserts into the table like it would if I hardcoded the file address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example procedure that accepts XML as a string, and shreds it into tables.  It's pretty gnarly to write this by hand, if you're doing many of these best to write some sort of generator based on your table definition.

The inputted xml is pretty simple, and attribute based

```
<xml>
<agent addr1='123 Main Street' city='Toronto' />
<agent addr1='123 Main Street' city='Toronto' />
</xml>

if exists (select * from dbo.sysobjects where id = object_id(N'[dbo].[sp_INSERT_agents]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
drop procedure [dbo].[sp_INSERT_agents]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE sp_INSERT_agents
     @strXML ntext
AS
BEGIN
    -- NOTE: This procedure was generated by WCG:ITX DB/XML mapping utility
    -- Please do not update this code by hand.
    DECLARE @RC int
    DECLARE @iDoc int
    DECLARE @dtcurrenttime datetime
    SET @dtcurrenttime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    -- Field variables

    DECLARE @addr1 varchar(50)
    DECLARE @addr2 varchar(50)
    DECLARE @agentid char(13)
    DECLARE @city varchar(50)
    DECLARE @email varchar(50)
    DECLARE @fax varchar(25)
    DECLARE @mobile varchar(25)
    DECLARE @muli char(1)
    DECLARE @name varchar(50)
    DECLARE @notes varchar(500)
    DECLARE @phone varchar(25)
    DECLARE @state char(2)
    DECLARE @zip varchar(10)
    DECLARE @part char(1)
    EXECUTE sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, @strXML

    -- Create a temporary return table
    create table #return
    ( err varchar(50), agentid char(13))

    -- Set NOCOUNT ON, to allow data to be returned from the temporary table.
    SET NOCOUNT ON 


    DECLARE @ElementCursor  CURSOR
    SET @ElementCursor = CURSOR SCROLL DYNAMIC FOR 
    SELECT addr1, addr2, agentid, city, email, fax, mobile, muli, name, notes, phone, state, zip, part FROM OPENXML( @iDoc, "//agent", 2 ) 
        WITH( addr1 varchar(50) '@addr1', addr2 varchar(50) '@addr2', agentid char(13) '@dt', city varchar(50) '@city', email varchar(50) '@email', fax varchar(25) '@fax', mobile varchar(25) '@mobile', muli char(1) '@muli', name varchar(50) '@name', notes varchar(500) '@notes', phone varchar(25) '@phone', state char(2) '@state', zip varchar(10) '@zip', part char(1) '@part')

    OPEN @ElementCursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM @ElementCursor INTO @addr1, @addr2, @agentid, @city, @email, @fax, @mobile, @muli, @name, @notes, @phone, @state, @zip, @part

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        -- Convert any temp values to real date time values

        BEGIN
            INSERT into dbo.agents
            (addr1, addr2, agentid, city, email, fax, mobile, muli, name, notes, phone, state, zip, part, dtmodified)
            values
            (@addr1, @addr2, @agentid, @city, @email, @fax, @mobile, @muli, @name, @notes, @phone, @state, @zip, @part, @dtcurrenttime)
        END

        -- Check for any errors on the insert / update
        IF @@error <> 0
        BEGIN
            INSERT into #return
            (err)
      values
      (@@error)
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM @ElementCursor INTO @addr1, @addr2, @agentid, @city, @email, @fax, @mobile, @muli, @name, @notes, @phone, @state, @zip, @part


    END



    COMMIT TRANSACTION


    CLOSE @ElementCursor
    DEALLOCATE @ElementCursor
    EXECUTE sp_xml_removedocument @iDoc

    -- Return the temporary data, containing any errors
    SELECT * from #return
END
GO
```